# How to synchronize chrome browser via windows and ubuntu?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, ubuntu-10.04, sync, bookmarks

I am using google chrome on both OS and it would be nice if they update each others bookmarks, cookies, history etc. automatically. Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about cookies, history etc. but you can just enable chrome sync and it will synchronize a lot of info between your chrome sessions.

This requires a working google -account though.